# Filter interval dates in R with dplyr

Tags: r, date, dplyr

I have a dataset with dates in tibble format from tidyverse/dplyr.

```
library(tidyverse)
A = seq(from = as.Date("2019/1/1"),to=as.Date("2022/1/1"), length.out = 252*3)
length(A)
x = rnorm(252*3)
d = tibble(A,x);d
```

Resulting to :

```
# A tibble: 756 x 2
   A                 x
   <date>        <dbl>
 1 2019-01-01  1.43   
 2 2019-01-02  0.899  
 3 2019-01-03  0.658  
 4 2019-01-05 -0.0720 
 5 2019-01-06 -1.99   
 6 2019-01-08 -0.743  
 7 2019-01-09  0.426  
 8 2019-01-11  0.00675
 9 2019-01-12  0.967  
10 2019-01-14 -0.606  
# ... with 746 more rows
```

i also have a date of interest, say:

```
start = as.Date("2021/12/15");start
```

I want to subset the dataset from this specific date (start) and one year back. But the year has 252 observations.
i tried :

```
 d%>%
  dplyr::filter(A<start)%>%
  dplyr::slice_tail(n=252)
```

but i don't like it because my real dataset has more than one factor label and if i use this then i will have 252 observations.

i also tried :

```
LAST_YEAR = DATE-365
d%>%
 dplyr::filter(Date <= DATE  & Date >=LAST_YEAR)
```

which works but i want to use the 252.Imagine that i want to find 2 years (252*2) back how many observations i have on this specific time interval.

Any help how i can do that?

Comment: because 252 are the trading days of one year.So imagine when i want from the start date and back 252 observations i actually want one year.

Comment: But those 252 trading days are all contained within 1 calendar year. So your calendar day comparison works just fine.

Comment: i thought maybe there is an alternative that i don't know and someone knows

Comment: Of course there are ways, like run length encoding your dates, but I think you will be much more likely to get an answer if you can explain *why* you want to do it one way rather than the clear solution you already have.

Comment: Couldn't you just use `d%>% dplyr::filter(A<start & A>(start-lubridate::years(n)) )` where `n` is the number of years you desire to go back?